# HTML problem in Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Please could someone help?
This works perfectly with Safari, Firefox and Chrome but NOT in Explorer and I have no clue why.

Thanks much.

```
<HEAD>
<body link="#FFCC66" vlink="#FFCC66" topmargin="5" alink="#FFCC66" style="text-align:left; background-attachment:fixed" bgcolor="#F3BC3A" leftmargin="50" background="/pictures/bg111uphbl.jpg">

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content=" "></meta>
<title>Text</title>
<meta name=" "></meta>



<style type="text/css" media="screen">

#menu {
width: 100%;
background: #eee;
float: left;
}

#menu ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 9em;
float: left;
}

#menu a, #menu h2 {
font: bold 11px/10px arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
display: block;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #ccc #888 #555 #bbb;
margin: 0;
padding: 2px 3px;
}

#menu h2 {
color: #fff;
background: #000;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu a {
color: #000;
background: #efefef;
text-decoration: none;
}

#menu a:hover {
color: #a00;
background: #fff;
}

#menu li {position: relative;}

#menu ul ul {
position: absolute;
z-index: 500;
}

#menu ul ul ul {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 100%;
}

div#menu ul ul ul,
div#menu ul li:hover ul ul ul,
div#menu ul ul li:hover ul ul ul
{display: none;}

div#menu ul ul,
div#menu ul li:hover ul ul,
div#menu ul ul li:hover ul ul,
div#menu ul ul ul li:hover ul ul
{display: none;}

div#menu ul li:hover ul,
div#menu ul ul li:hover ul,
div#menu ul ul ul li:hover ul,
div#menu ul ul ul ul li:hover ul
{display: block;}


</style>
</div>

<div style="position: absolute; width: 880px; height: 50px; z-index: 1; left: 10px; top: 3px" id="layer1"> 

<div style="position: absolute; width: 880px; height: 600px; z-index: 1; left: -1px; top: 15px" id="layer2">

<!-- start menu HTML -->
<div id="menu" style="width: 880px; height: 20px">
<ul>

<li><h2>Text</h2>

<ul>

<li><a href="http://bricemallier.com/Menus.htm">Text</a><ul>

              <li><a href="http://bricemallier.com/Menus.htm">Text</a><ul></li>

</table>
</div>


</html>
```

Comment: You're missing the opening `<html>` tag. Does your actual webpage have it? What happens in IE? What version of IE are you testing? What is supposed to happen?

Comment: Your markup is terribly formed. Head->Body->Title?  No starting html tag, no ending head/body tags...

Comment: This code crashes the W3C validator.

Comment: Ahaha, it actually does! That's awesome.

Comment: your kidding, it actually does i figured that was sarcastic?!

Comment: Yeah I thought maybe it would just throw a bunch of errors, but it really crashes with an array reference exception

Comment: Wow !!! now I have a perfect valid test case to show my boss 'How to crash the W3C validator' ;)

Answer (score 1):

The tags in your unordered list are all out of whack, you have several opening <ul> tags and no closings, I bet if you fixed that it would fix whatever the problem is. I also just noticed you also have a closing </table> tag with no matching opening tag.  You should run this code through a validator, it'll help you find a lot of these issues.

Comment: The more I look at this the more I realize the whole thing is a mess, you need to go back and read through your code carefully and make sure that you are closing tags that you have opened in the right places.  It looks to me like you copied a lot of this and pasted it in without reading through it.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your issues stem from IE resorting to quirks mode rather than standards mode like the other browsers.

I'd highly suggest you take a minute to fix your markup, and once you have valid HTML add this doctype definition to the top of your html page (before the starting `<html>` tag, which you don't actually have at the moment...)

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a mess. Go through it and clean up all your tags. Its probably not working in IE because does not read badly written code as smoothly as the other browswers. Close your head tag and the body tag should go after the meta. There is also a random `</div>` tag after style and a `</table>` tag before the last `</div>` and your `<ul>` tags aren't closed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I am learning but I have been successful! Please do tell me if there are still things wrong.

```
<title>Text</title>
<meta name="description" content="text">
<meta name="keywords" content="text">
```

## menu {

width: 100%;
background: #eee;
float: left;
}

## menu ul {

list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 9em;
float: left;
}

## menu a, #menu h2 {

font: bold 11px/10px arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
display: block;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #ccc #888 #555 #bbb;
margin: 0;
padding: 2px 3px;
}

## menu h2 {

color: #fff;
background: #000;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

## menu a {

color: #000;
background: #efefef;
text-decoration: none;
}

## menu a:hover {

color: #a00;
background: #fff;
}

## menu li {position: relative;}

## menu ul ul {

position: absolute;
z-index: 500;
}

## menu ul ul ul {

position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 100%;
}

div#menu ul ul ul,
div#menu ul li:hover ul ul ul,
div#menu ul ul li:hover ul ul ul
{display: none;}

div#menu ul ul,
div#menu ul li:hover ul ul,
div#menu ul ul li:hover ul ul,
div#menu ul ul ul li:hover ul ul
{display: none;}

div#menu ul li:hover ul,
div#menu ul ul li:hover ul,
div#menu ul ul ul li:hover ul,
div#menu ul ul ul ul li:hover ul
{display: block;}

- ### Text

  - [Test](http://bricemallier.com/Test.htm)

    - [Test](http://bricemallier.com/Test.htm)

Comment: This is not a forum.  You should only put answers here.  This should be added to your original post.